# Caesar Cipher in Python 3.4.3

Tags: python, chr, caesar-cipher, ord

The output I should get if I type in "eat" should be "hdw" if I shift it by 3. However, the end result is only "w". I'm pretty sure I have everything I need, but maybe it's the formatting?

```
def shifter():  
    phrase = input("Please enter a message: ")  
    key = eval(input("Please enter the number of places to be shifted: "))  
    list = phrase.split()  
    for word in list:  
        for ch in word:  
           conversion = (chr)((ord(ch) - ord("a") + key) % 26 + ord("a"))  
        newPhrase = " "  
        newPhrase = newPhrase + conversion  
    print(newPhrase)  
shifter()
```

Comment: you need a number but why you need `eval`... try `int`.

Comment: Using `eval` to convert types is just plain stupid, as it creates an enormous security problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are setting conversion inside your for loop, instead of appending to it, so only the last character in the word is appended to the newPhrase at the end.

You should be appending to conversion, rather than setting it.

Also, you should initialize `newPhrase` outside the loop and then append to it inside.

Example -

```
def shifter():  
    phrase = input("Please enter a message: ")  
    key = eval(input("Please enter the number of places to be shifted: "))  
    list = phrase.split()
    newPhrase = ""
    for word in list:
        conversion = '' 
        for ch in word:  
           conversion += (chr)((ord(ch) - ord("a") + key) % 26 + ord("a"))  
        newPhrase = newPhrase + conversion + " " 
    print(newPhrase)  
shifter()
```

Comment: I noticed that in comparison to my coding, you also added 
conversion = ' '
and I think that might've been the pivotal point. I've tried adding 
newPhrase = " "
before the for loop, and it's done nothing. So I appreciate the help!

Comment: Thats one of the main point, the most main point is `conversion =` changed to `conversion +=` (for appending instead of directly setting)

Comment: @RickyRodSpanish the key point is that you need to do concatenation for every char that you got in the loop `for ch in word`.  Just as Anand S Kumar showed.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's with your indenting!
Right now, before you do anything with the variable conversion, you've already looped through every ch in word, so you're stuck at the last ch.

Try doing conversion += ... Instead of conversion = ...
(You might need to initialize conversion before that but idts.)

Comment: That actually turned out to be a MAJOR part of the solution, so thank you. I looked up what that += thing does, and it essentially takes the left part of the equation and adds it to itself while some other equation can happen on the right side. Sorry if I sound confusing, but I'm not good with words.